# Snap.svg Drag coordinates inside a responsive viewbox

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, svg, snap.svg

Figuring out snap.svg, and like the title says, I have a view box that is being resized via Bootstrap's image-responsive, which works great until I try to drag, then the coordinates just become skewed.

Codepen: http://codepen.io/k3no/pen/mWPqwm

Heres the JS code:

```
  var s = Snap("#snappy");
  var circle = s.circle(600, 350, 100);

  circle.attr({
      fill: "tomato",
      stroke: "cornflowerblue",
      strokeWidth: 20
  });
  circle.drag();
```

And HTML:

```
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-sm-12">
      <svg id='snappy' class='img-responsive' viewBox="0 0 1200 700"></svg>         
      </div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The default drag doesn't take any transforms or changes in the transformation from the screen to the viewbox etc into account. So one way I've got around this is to write a plugin to deal with that.

Basically it works by taking the dx/dy changes accounting for the transform applying to it.

[Example plugin in use](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/aJNYJo)

```
Snap.plugin( function( Snap, Element, Paper, global ) {

    Element.prototype.altDrag = function() {
        this.drag( dragMove, dragStart, dragEnd );
        return this;
    }

    var dragStart = function ( x,y,ev ) {
        this.data('ot', this.transform().local );
    }


    var dragMove = function(dx, dy, ev, x, y) {
        var tdx, tdy;
        var snapInvMatrix = this.transform().diffMatrix.invert();
        snapInvMatrix.e = snapInvMatrix.f = 0;
        tdx = snapInvMatrix.x( dx,dy ); tdy = snapInvMatrix.y( dx,dy );
        this.transform( "t" + [ tdx, tdy ] + this.data('ot')  );

    }

    var dragEnd = function() {
    }
});
```

There's a slightly more complex version [here](http://svg.dabbles.info/snaptut-altdragnew) I have done previously, if you end up with things like nested transforms, but it's probably overkill for your example here.